# PHP import classes or namespaces?

Tags: php, namespaces

Most of the project I bumped into were using namespaces to import the classes directly. I wonder whether this is a standard or a matter of preference to import the classes only and not the whole namespaces?

Please see the below examples. The first way seems better to me as I don't have to include each class separately.

Import the namespaces:

```
use Project\Model;
use Project\Helper;

// and then

Model\Foobar::findAll();
Helper\Foobar::doSomething();
```

Import the classes only:

```
use Project\Model\Foobar as ModelFoobar;
use Project\Helper\Foobar as HelperFoobar;

// and then

ModelFoobar::findAll();
HelperFoobar::doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a matter of preference. Either way looks compatible to [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) standars so it should be safe. I prefer the second way since it provides an overview at the top of your script about what classes it uses. This was discussed in IRC recently, Rob Allen has a [good summary](http://akrabat.com/php/use-statements/).